# Remark about connected sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E$ is connected set and $A$ is a subset of $E$. Also $A\neq \varnothing$ and $A$ is closed and open set. Prove that $A=E$.

My thought: Let $A\subsetneq E$ then $E=A\cup A^c$ where $A$ and $A^c$ are separated nonempty sets. Then $E$ is not connected. Contradiction.

Hence $A=E$.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, though perhaps you should explain why $A$ and $A^C$ are separated.

Comment: @AlexS, Since $A$ closed and open. Then $\overline{A}\cap A^c=A\cap A^c=\varnothing$. Case $\overline{A^c}\cap A$ is analogous. Right?

Comment: @AlexS, Thanks for help!

Comment: This hinges on your definition of connected.